# Get posts that do not have the same tags as current

Tags: wp-query, loop, tags, query-posts

I'm trying to get all posts in a custom plugin loop that DO NOT share the same tag as the current one.

I'm trying:

```php
$events = tribe_get_events([
    'start_date'     => 'now',
    'eventDisplay'   => 'list',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tag'            => $current_tag // <-- Trying to do the exact opposite of this
]);
```

I'm using https://theeventscalendar.com/ 's plugin. But under the hood, that just uses the normal WP args setup.

Is there a way to invert the tag selection to get posts that DO NOT have that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question:

If I use the `tax_query` arg then I could specify `'operator'  => 'NOT IN'` like so:

```php
$events = tribe_get_events([
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $current_tag,
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN' // HERE
        )
        ),
    'start_date'     => 'now',
    'eventDisplay'   => 'list',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
]);
```

Comment: Be aware of the potential [performance issues](https://docs.wpvip.com/technical-references/code-quality-and-best-practices/using-post__not_in/) with this approach.